# Unit testing GORM associations with sqlmock

Tags: unit-testing, go, go-gorm, go-sqlmock

I'm working on my first Go + Gin + GORM project. I've two models: `List` and `Todo` as follows:

```golang
type List struct {
    gorm.Model

    Name        string

    Todos []*Todo `gorm:"many2many:list_todos;"`
}

type Todo struct {
    gorm.Model

    Title       string

    Lists []*List `gorm:"many2many:list_todos;"`
}
```

I've a helper function to add a `Todo` to a `List`:

```golang
func (self *List) AddTodos(db *gorm.DB, todos ...*Todo) error {
    return db.Model(self).Association("Todos").Append(todos)
}
```

I want to unit test the `AddTodos` function. I'm using `sqlmock` for mocking. This is the code for the unit test:

```golang
func TestAddTodosWithNoTodos(t *testing.T) {
    gormDB, db, mock, _ := misc.GetMockedGormDBWithMock()
    defer db.Close()

    mockList := &List{
        Model: gorm.Model{ID: 1},
    }

    mock.NewRows([]string{"id"}).AddRow(mockList.ID)

    if err := mockList.AddTodos(gormDB); err != nil {
        // test fails here
        t.Errorf("Expected no error, got %v", err)
    }

    todos := []Todo{}
    if err := gormDB.Model(mockList).Association("Todos").Find(&todos); err != nil {
        // test also fails here
        t.Errorf("Expected no error, got %v", err)
    }

    if len(todos) != 0 {
        t.Errorf("Expected no todos, got %v", todos)
    }
}
```

I've marked the two places where the test fails. The `error` object being checked at both these places are from GORM, however, in the test failure error messages, it is revealed that `sqlmock` is causing these errors:

First error message:

```
Expected no error, got all expectations were already fulfilled, call to database transaction Begin was not expected
```

Second error message:

```
Expected no error, got all expectations were already fulfilled
```

I don't want to test which queries are executed, hence, I've not used `sqlmock`'s `ExpectQuery`. Still, "unexpected queries" are causing errors.

How can I unit test `AddTodos` without testing the queries it performs?

Comment: any updates on this @csmathhc. I recently started workign on golang and facing similar problem gorm unit testing.

Comment: Too bad, still no update on this question